# Moving files from one folder to another on different servers

Tags: cron

I have a shell script which moves some files from one folder to another.
This shell script is being run on 3 different servers manually. Is there a way to write a cron job to move the files in the first server, give a 5-10 minutes gap and run it on the second server and then again give a 5-10 minutes gap and run it on the third server.
This is the script which moves the files
cd /a/
ls -lrt |head -100|awk '{print $9}'|xargs mv -t /b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for loop and do your repetitive tasks say like below

```
remote_server1=192.168.1.1
remote_server2=192.168.1.2
remote_server3=192.168.1.3

for i in $remote_server1 $remote_server1 $remote_server1
 do
#execute your remote commands
   error_check=$(ssh user1@$i 'cd /a/; ls -lrt |head -100|awk '{print $9}'|xargs mv -t /b')

   if [ -z "$error_check" ];then
     echo "move was not successful"
   else 
     echo "move was successful"
   fi 
done
```

Try this out in a script and see if it helps

Comment: When I execute this script, it asks 3 times for the password and then it says permission denied. Should we also give the password somewhere in the script?

Comment: The above code worked for me. Thanks for the solution, but ca you please explain the condition that we are checking in the if statement.

Comment: The if statement is trying to do an error check. Once the remote commands are executed we need to see if they are executed properly or not so the if is to check if the command executed properly. Happy that the code worked :)